# ESlint gives error about the indexer signature in class

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have a simple class with an indexer signature:

```
class Test {
  [key: string]: any
}
```

It could be compiled by tsc but the eslint would give an error about this:

```
'key' is not defined. eslint no-undef
(parameter) key: string
```

Here is the config in .eslintrc.json.

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "google"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "object-curly-spacing": "off",
        "camelcase": "off",
        "new-cap": "off",
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
        "no-invalid-this": "off",
        "no-unused-vars": [
            "warn",
            {
                "ignoreRestSiblings": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "globals": {
        "JSX": "readonly"
    }
}
```

How can I get rid of this eslint error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options

1. Remove the `eslint:recommended` extend, `google` extend is enough.
2. Set `'no-undef': 0` in rule, it's not recommond to use `no-undef` in TS file, TS will check undef by itself

Comment: Option 1 is fine for me. Thanks.