# Store postman body JSON properties inside Typescript class with multiple optional properties

Tags: typescript, class, ecmascript-6

I am developing an API which I am calling from Postman. The POST request body looks like this:-

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "username": "john123"
}
```

I am storing this request body in a constant which is of type `MyRequest`:-

`const myRequest = new MyRequest(req.body);`

where `MyRequest` is a Typescript class:-

```
export default class MyRequest {
    public name: string;
    public username: string;

    constructor(data: any) {
        this.name = data.name;
        this.username = data.username;
    }
}
```

Now my requirement is, there can be multiple optional and unknown JSON body parameters in the Postman request, like so:-

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "username": "john123",
    "age": 10,
    "address": "somewhere",
    "some_new_key": "some_new_value",
    .
    .
    .
    .
    "another_new_key": "another_new_value"
}
```

I need to store all of these values in `MyRequest`, where only `name` and `username` is mandatory, and all other fields are optional, and then initialize them in the constructor. How do I write the `MyRequest` class?

Comment: constructor(data: any) {
        this.name = data.name;
        this.username = data.username;
        this.age = this.age ? this.age: '';
.......
....

    }
try something like this

Comment: Are you saying that you don't know what the properties of the response other than "name" and "username", but you'd like to still populate them into the class instance? If you know what all properties are going to be there, you can mark the other properties as optional...

Comment: yes, if the properties are optional then we mark them optional in the constructor too

Comment: @rajanbhadauria I wouldn't know the property names beforehand

Comment: @Sh4dy then you may create objects dynamically like the - 

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
  //console.log('Key : ' + key + ', Value : ' + data[key])
  new_data[key] =  data[key]
})

Comment: @Sh4dy Then why are you even creating a `class` for that? Declare an `interface` at best, and just use a type assertion: `const myRequest = req.body as IMyRequest;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add properties to the class dynamically by adding them to the *this* instance inside the **constructor** method.

```
interface MyRequestInterface {
  name: string;
  username: string;
  [key: string]: string | number ;
}

class MyRequest {
    public name: string;
    public username: string;
    [key: string]: string | number ;

    constructor(data: MyRequestInterface) {
        this.name = data.name;
        this.username = data.username;
        Object.keys(data).forEach((e) => {
          this[e] = data[e];
        })
    }
}

const data: MyRequestInterface = {
    name: "John",
    username: "john123",
    age: 10,
    address: "somewhere",
    some_new_key: "some_new_value",
    another_new_key: "another_new_value"
}

const request = new MyRequest(data)

console.log(request.name)
```

Comment: I'm getting an ESLint error for the index signature declaration in the class: 'key' is not defined. Any idea? It doesn't throw an error in the interface though.

Comment: Never mind, found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68355431/eslint-gives-error-about-the-indexer-signature-in-class